# Error in Bash Shell Script IF Statement

Tags: bash, macos, sh

I'm trying to get this to run as a launchd, I have setup the plist and enabled the watch path to check when students modify Remote Management.

I want an if statement that checks to see if the ARD agent is running and of not runs the kickstart command.

When the service is not running it works perfectly. but when the service is already running I get this error

```
/Users/user/Desktop/test.sh: line 3: [[: 14682  0   com.apple.RemoteDesktop.agent: syntax error in expression (error token is "0    com.apple.RemoteDesktop.agent")
```

Here is the script;

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ $(launchctl list | grep '^\d.*RemoteDesktop.*') -eq "" ]]; then
    sudo    sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -users admin -access -on -privs -all
else
    exit 0
fi
```

If anyone could help it would be much appreciated.

Comment: `launchd` is running your script with `/bin/sh`, not `/bin/bash`, so `[[` is not a legal command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use quotes and write `"$(launchctl list ...)"`, but it's probably cleaner to do:

```
#!/bin/bash

if ! launchctl list | grep -q '^\d.*RemoteDesktop.*'; then
    sudo /System/Library/CoreServices/RemoteManagement/ARDAgent.app/Contents/Resources/kickstart -activate -configure -users admin -access -on -privs -all
else
    exit 0
fi
```